# bash: vera++Report2checkstyleReport.perl: command not found

Tags: sonarqube, vera++

On `Ubuntu-18.04` I am trying to generate `vera++ report to import in SonarQube`. Where as it fails with below error.

```
bash -c 'find src -regex ".*\.cc\|.*\.hh" | vera++ - -showrules -nodup 2>&1 | vera++Report2checkstyleReport.perl > /sonar-test/valgrind-test/sonar-cxx/sonar-cxx-plugin/src/samples/SampleProject2/build/vera++-report.xml'
bash: vera++Report2checkstyleReport.perl: command not found
```

I have installed `vera++ - 1.2.1` version. But I don't have `vera++Report2checkstyleReport.perl` file. Do I need to download separately? Could I please have an explanation that how this should get work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i have downloaded the below file and executed now it is working fine.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#  An vera++ to checkstyle XML report generator for
# Copyright (C) 2010 - 2011, Neticoa SAS France - Tous droits réservés.
# Author(s) : Franck Bonin, Neticoa SAS France.
#
#  This Software is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
#  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
#  version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
# 
#  Sonar is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
#  Lesser General Public License for more details.
# 
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#  License along with This Software; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02
#  _________________________________________________________________________

use strict;

##my $rapport = $ARGV[0];
##chomp $rapport;
##open (DATAFILE, "$rapport") || die("Can't open $rapport\n");

my ($file,$line,$rule,$comment);

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
print "<checkstyle version=\"5.0\">\n";

my $lastfile = "";
while (<STDIN>)
{
    chomp $_;
    ## replace '(RULENumber)' with 'RULENumber:'
    $_ =~ s/(.*) \((.*)\) (.*)/\1\2:\3/g;

    ($file,$line,$rule,$comment) = split(":", $_);

    my $severity = "error";

    $severity = "warning";
    #if ($rule =~ m/G.*/) { $severity = "ignore"; }
    #if ($rule =~ m/F.*/) { $severity = "info"; }
    #if ($rule =~ m/L.*/) { $severity = "warning"; }
    #if ($rule =~ m/T.*/) { $severity = "error"; }
    if ($file ne $lastfile)
    {
        if ($lastfile ne "")
        {
            print "\t</file>\n";
        }
        print "\t<file name=\"$file\">\n";
        $lastfile = $file;
    }
    print "\t\t<error line=\"$line\" severity=\"$severity\" message=\"$comment\" source=\"$rule\"/>\n";
}
if ($lastfile ne "")
{
    print "\t</file>\n";
}
print "</checkstyle>\n";
```